# Can't install Android Studio due to JDK Error

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I tried installing Android Studio, but I fail every time due to a JDK error.
Even when I select the requested path the installer still can't find it.
I have added the `JAVA_HOME` and `JAVA_JDK` variables with no luck.
Mind that when I open `CMD` and type `java -version` I get `1.7.0_79` and with the `javac -version` command I get `1.7.0_79`.

Anything else I should try?

Comment: Please check 'javac' is working or not using simple java program on your machine..!!

Comment: I have Eclipse which runs perfectly fine so I dunno where the problem is. Could it be a bug in Android Studio installer?

Answer (score 1):

1.First open the Control Panel.

2.Uninstall every JDK you have installed.

3.Install JDK 1.7 or later.

4.Install Android Studio on the same drive where you installed JDK to.

Comment: Unistalled and reinstalled the JDK 1.7 but the error persists!

Comment: then try with jdk1.8